# Flagged answer declined but gone

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags, deleted-answers, not-an-answer

My [flag summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/2083613) includes this one:

[image: flag summary item]

The question title [directly links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502913/how-to-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-folder-by-cmd-call/32337085#32337085) the alleged answer, but there is none by user “Zach” at `/32337085#32337085.` While I can’t verify, I suppose there *were* some evidence to argue against an answer, especially with the flagged answer now obviously removed, still counting as actually being not only disputed, but declined.

**Is there a way to find out what has happened to the answer?** Or to retrieve it?

Comment: It was deleted. You can't see deleted posts below 10k reputation. NAA flagging reason shouldn't be used for technical reasons BTW.

Comment: Presumably, the mod who deleted it came over it himself later, saw a reason to delete it *not* covered by your flag and thus declined but deleted, or was alerted by a custom flag which gave an adequate reason later. In any case, as πάνταῥεῖ said your flag was inappropriate.

Comment: What do you mean by “technical resons”? Beacuse I can’t tell what the reasons were, since it’s gone. Why was it “inappropriate in any case”? Because you two can see its contents, or because it was the decition of a moderator?

Answer (score 3):

The question asked:

> I want to delete all files and folders in a folder by system call.

The answer said:

> ```
> net stop wuauserv
>
> DEL "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\*.*" /s /q
>
> rmdir /s /q "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\" 
>
> net start wuauserv
> ```

Which not only answers a question but answers the question. But don't try that at home, it might have unwanted side-effects.

When an answer looks like it answers a question, Not An Answer flags are not the correct action to take. Down votes and comments are much more effective because that enables 20K-ers to delete vote such answers.

Moderators don't know if answers are good or incorrect. The moderator who deleted the answer knows a bit about Python but don't expect them to know if disabling Windows Update service is okay. Moderators declined your flag to signal to you the wrong use of your flag.

You might read the [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) to understand when NAA is the correct flag to raise. And also [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

**tl;dr** don't use it for answers that seem incorrect.

Comment: Was "knows a bit about Python" deliberate understatement? Based on the top users in that tag I would assume so!